# Validating a URL

Tags: url, validation

Is there a way to validate that an input URL is valid? For example, I've created a sheet that uses information from a different sheet we'll call 'A', but it changes to a new sheet we'll call 'B' every month. I've created an alert that requests the user to input a new URL at the beginning of the month, but how do I check to make sure it's a valid site before trying to pull data from it?

Comment: I'd use regex, With regex you can put specific design patterns, and then you can check to see if it's valid based on the wildcard patterns.

Comment: I've never used regex - i'm self-taught in this and started about a month ago, so I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Using [regex](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) you can write to file check in which will undergo testing of url and action is made if it changed. Then it is necessary to include this file to the page on which Url need to check.

Answer (score 0):

```
      function ping($host, $port, $timeout) {    
         $tB = microtime(true);   
         $fP = fSockOpen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);  
         if (!$fP) { return "down"; }    
         $tA = microtime(true);    
         return round((($tA - $tB) * 1000), 0)." ms";  }

        //Echoing it will display the ping if the host is up, if not it'll say
      "down". 

        echo ping("www.google.com", 80, 10);
```

another :-

```
function urlExists($url=NULL)  
{  
    if($url == NULL) return false;  
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    curl_close($ch);  
    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```